# I want to use FallbackManager

Tags: gnosis-safe

I would like to use Gnosis Safe for the wallets managed by our board members.
There is one problem, however.
The token we issue is ERC223, and if the destination address is a contract, it will result in an error if the specified function is not implemented.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1a3496c18d558bd9c6c8f609e1b129f67ab08163#code
Look at line 622 of the code here.
So I want to set the fallbackHandler during setup.
The handler's contract will be provided mine.

What procedures do I need to follow?

[Postscript below]

https://github.com/Akira-Taniguchi/gnosis-safe-fallback-handler/blob/main/contracts/FallbakHandler.sol

When I was creating and testing the contract I wanted to Fallback, I noticed something. I just realized that DEAP coins can be managed in Gnosis without having to set up a fallbackhandler in Gnosis setup.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1a3496c18d558bd9c6c8f609e1b129f67ab08163#code
Look at line 622 of the code here.

If the to address is a contract address, the tokenFallback function is executed, but I noticed that if the fallbackHandler is not set in Gnosis safe, no processing is performed.
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/FallbackManager.sol#L38

I thought I could manage DEAP coins with Gnosis safe without doing anything special (not using FallbackHandler), but I am correct in this understanding.

I would like a reply.

Comment: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/pull/411

Comment: I add pull request your product